# Powershell Script | Create New Web application in Sharepoint 2019

Tags: azure, sharepoint

Can someone share powershell script of creating new web application in Sharepoint 2019 WITH **SQL SA authentication**? I have found so many scripts which just talk to windows authtication of SQL Server but I have **Azure managed SQL instance** linked with Sharepoint server 2019.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By doing some research I got working script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
#Define Variables for Web Application Creation
$WebAppName = "abc.xyz.com" 
$WebAppURL = "http://abc01"
$WebAppPort = 9000
$ContentDBName = "WSS_Contents_Abc"
$AppPoolName = "SPABC"
$AppPoolAccount = "Test\ABC"
$DatabaseServer = "sql-managedinstance-902932test.net" #Alias of your DB Server
#Authentication Provider
$AuthProvider = New-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication 
-DisableKerberos $FarmAccountLogin = "Test\ABCSQL";
$FarmAcountObj = Get-Credential -Credential $FarmAccountLogin; 
#Create new Web Application
New-SPWebApplication -name $WebAppName -port $WebAppPort -URL $WebAppURL - 
ApplicationPool $AppPoolName -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount 
$AppPoolAccount) -AuthenticationMethod NTLM -AuthenticationProvider 
$AuthProvider -DatabaseServer $DatabaseServer -DatabaseCredentials 
$FarmAcountObj -DatabaseName $ContentDBName
```

Comment: That really helped me, Its working as expected.